# Getting dyld: Symbol not found: _UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter when trying to run my app in ipod touch?

Tags: iphone

Hello everyone I am getting dyld: `Symbol not found: _UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`

when trying to run my app in `ipod touch`.

Here is my xcode project setting - `Deployment Target = 5.0. iPod touch OS version = 5.1`. Any ideas? the project is working on a `iPhone 3GS ios 6.0.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UICollectionView` class (and so all constants declared for it) is available starting from iOS 6.0 only, so you cannot use it in older iOS versions.

If you still want to support iOS older than 6.0 you can use [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) library, which copies `UICollectionView` functionality and interface + it uses actual `UICollectionView` class when your app is being run on iOS 6+